# Duplicated the same code due to if statement

Tags: java, android, xml

I'm currently working on my University GPA tracker app (I'm a novice developer).  The homepage of the app works good on portrait mode but I have several issues regarding my app.  I appreciate all help.

1. I know the onSavedInstance has been answered here before but I don't know how to incorporate it to my code.  I'm not just looking for answers.  I'd really appreciate it if someone could explain it to me.  All my views get lost when I rotate and I know this is due to onSavedInstanceState.
2. When the orientation changes, I found that a grid layout of 3 columns was more appropriate.  2 colums for (up to) 8 buttons and the last column on the right for the floatActionButton so I created a separate xml directory and file for the landscape orientation.  I think the layout works fine but it doesn't populate and crashes everytime due to a problem I have on line 82 (I followed the documentation for that but it says that it can't run the onClick method of the method I attributed to my FAB on xml).
3. My floatActionButton, when scrolling the app down, moves down with the app.  Each time I scroll the layout or click it to add more views, the FAB just drops down.
4. I created 2 if statements to handle the dynamic view addition per orientation change but I ended up repeating the code and the Java looks like a mess.

I'm sorry for presenting you with such mess of a code.

My landscape xml file

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<ScrollView
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:fillViewport="true"
    >

    <GridLayout
        android:id="@+id/semester_grid_layout"
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
        android:background="#FFFFFF"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:columnCount="3"
        android:rowCount="4"
        xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
        tools:context="myapp.onur.journeygpacalculator.MainActivity">


            <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
                android:id="@+id/addActionButton"
                android:layout_column="2"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:layout_margin="16dp"
                android:clickable="true"
                android:onClick="onFloatActionButtonClick"
                android:longClickable="true"
                app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
                android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
                app:borderWidth="0dp"
                android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp" />

    </GridLayout>
    </ScrollView>
```

My regular xml layout

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>

<RelativeLayout
    xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="#FFFFFF"
    tools:context="myapp.onur.journeygpacalculator.MainActivity">

    <ScrollView
        xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:fillViewport="true"
        >
        <LinearLayout
            android:id="@+id/main_layout"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="vertical"
            android:padding="6dp">
        </LinearLayout>
    </ScrollView>

    <android.support.design.widget.FloatingActionButton
        android:id="@+id/addActionButton"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_alignParentEnd="true"
        android:layout_margin="16dp"
        android:clickable="true"
        android:longClickable="true"
        android:onClick="onFloatActionButtonClick"
        android:src="@drawable/ic_add_black_48dp"
        android:tint="@color/colorWhite"
        app:backgroundTint="@color/colorPrimary"
        android:elevation="6dp"
        app:borderWidth="0dp"/>
</RelativeLayout>
```

My MainActivity

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    int counter = 0;

    FloatingActionButton addingSemester;
    Button semesterButton;
    LinearLayout semesterLayout;
    GridLayout semesterGridLayout;
    RelativeLayout.LayoutParams lp = new RelativeLayout.LayoutParams(
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.MATCH_PARENT,
            AppBarLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        addingSemester = (FloatingActionButton) findViewById(R.id.addActionButton);
        semesterLayout = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.main_layout);
        semesterGridLayout = (GridLayout)findViewById(R.id.semester_grid_layout);
        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);

    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        MenuInflater menuInflater = getMenuInflater();
        menuInflater.inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
        return super.onCreateOptionsMenu(menu);
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        int id = item.getItemId();

        if (id == R.id.delete) {
            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
            .setTitle("Delete entry")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete everything?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            semesterLayout.removeAllViews();
                            counter = 0;
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            dialog.cancel();
                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);

    }

    public void onFloatActionButtonClick(View view) {
        float screenRotation = semesterLayout.getOrientation();
        semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
        if (counter < 8) {
            semesterButton.setId(counter + 1);
            semesterButton.setText("Semester " + (counter + 1));
            semesterButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
            semesterButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
            lp.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24);
            semesterButton.setLayoutParams(lp);

            if(screenRotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || screenRotation == Surface.ROTATION_180){
                semesterGridLayout.addView(semesterButton);
                counter++;
                semesterButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        final Button b = (Button) v;
                        b.setTag(b.getText().toString());
                        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        b.setText("Delete");

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Delete entry")
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        semesterGridLayout.removeView(b);
                                        counter--;
                                        for (int i = 0; i < semesterGridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                            ((Button) semesterGridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        b.cancelLongPress();
                                        b.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                                        b.setText(b.getTag().toString());
                                        dialog.cancel();

                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });

            }else if(screenRotation == Surface.ROTATION_90){
                semesterLayout.addView(semesterButton);
                counter++;
                semesterButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
                    @Override
                    public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
                        final Button b = (Button) v;
                        b.setTag(b.getText().toString());
                        b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
                        b.setText("Delete");

                        new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                                .setTitle("Delete entry")
                                .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                                .setCancelable(true)
                                .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        semesterLayout.removeView(b);
                                        counter--;
                                        for (int i = 0; i < semesterLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                            ((Button) semesterLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                                        }
                                    }
                                })
                                .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                                    public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                                        b.cancelLongPress();
                                        b.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                                        b.setText(b.getTag().toString());
                                        dialog.cancel();

                                    }
                                })
                                .show();
                        return true;
                    }
                });
            }

        } else if (counter == 8) {
            Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You cannot add more than 8 semesters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

**In response to item 4**, if you refactor blocks of code that are identical (or similar apart from parameters) into private methods, you will find the code is much easier to read and understand. Also, if code is executed for both paths of an if statement, then you can move that code outside:

```
public void onFloatActionButtonClick(View view) {
    float screenRotation = semesterLayout.getOrientation();
    semesterButton = new Button(MainActivity.this);
    if (counter < 8) {
        semesterButton.setId(counter + 1);
        semesterButton.setText("Semester " + (counter + 1));
        semesterButton.setBackgroundColor(getColor(R.color.colorPrimary));
        semesterButton.setTextColor(Color.WHITE);
        lp.setMargins(24, 24, 24, 24);
        semesterButton.setLayoutParams(lp);

        if (screenRotation == Surface.ROTATION_0 || screenRotation == Surface.ROTATION_180) {
            semesterGridLayout.addView(semesterButton);
        } else if (screenRotation == Surface.ROTATION_90) {
            semesterLayout.addView(semesterButton);
        }

        // these lines moved outside the if statement blocks
        counter++;
        setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton();

    } else if (counter == 8) {
        Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "You cannot add more than 8 semesters", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }
}

// this method refactored from the duplicated code
private void setOnLongClickListenerForSemesterButton() {
    semesterButton.setOnLongClickListener(new View.OnLongClickListener() {
        @Override
        public boolean onLongClick(View v) {
            final Button b = (Button) v;
            b.setTag(b.getText().toString());
            b.setBackgroundColor(Color.RED);
            b.setText("Delete");

            new AlertDialog.Builder(MainActivity.this)
                    .setTitle("Delete entry")
                    .setMessage("Are you sure you want to delete this entry?")
                    .setCancelable(true)
                    .setPositiveButton("Yes", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            semesterGridLayout.removeView(b);
                            counter--;
                            for (int i = 0; i < semesterGridLayout.getChildCount(); i++) {
                                ((Button) semesterGridLayout.getChildAt(i)).setText("Semester " + (i + 1));
                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .setNegativeButton("No", new DialogInterface.OnClickListener() {
                        public void onClick(DialogInterface dialog, int which) {
                            b.cancelLongPress();
                            b.setBackgroundColor(ContextCompat.getColor(MainActivity.this, R.color.colorPrimary));
                            b.setText(b.getTag().toString());
                            dialog.cancel();

                        }
                    })
                    .show();
            return true;
        }
    });
}
```

Comment: My stacktrace shows that this line `float screenRotation = semesterLayout.getOrientation();` is whats causing the crash when I try to add views on landscape mode.  Do you know why that would be?

Comment: Sorry, this answer is just a tip to help with the code duplication.